# Form has a div within it. How can I add classes to this div?

Tags: 7, forms

There's a div called `.description` in a form in the site I've inherited. I want to add a another class to the div.

The div's content is created within `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, eg:

```
$form['#description'] = 'Please enter your full name';
```

I've tried adding a classed to it like:

```
$form['#description'] = [
    '#markup' => '<div class="my-class">Please enter your full name</div>',
  ];
```

But this just results in "Array" being printed.

Would anyone know what I could do add a class to this element?

Comment: Why did you add an '`s`' in the second example? `#description` is not an element, its the description text - in this case it would be for the form itself. Does that text appear at the top of the form and not attached to anything?

Comment: @Kevin, oops typo. The text appears at the bottom of the form, but still within the form element, wrapped in it's own div `<div class="description">Please enter your full name</a>`. (I don't know where the description class is coming from.)

Answer (score 0):

That's not what you want. What you want to do is add it to the form structure like this:

```
$form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'my-class';
```

Since you didn't list an element on the form, I can only assume you want the class on the form itself. If you want to wrap an element with a div with a class on it, you can do:

```
$form['element']['#prefix'] = '<div class="my-class">';
$form['element']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

That will wrap the entire element.

Comment: Thanks, yes this adds the class to the wrapping `<form>` element, but I want to target the div element within that form element.

Comment: That comes from the core theming function theme_form_element: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/includes/form.inc?h=7.x#n4261 it is hardcoded there. To get around that, you would need to change the theme wrapper for this element to point to a custom one or add JS to add the class on (not preferable). I am not sure if there is a contrib module to help this, I don't know of one off the top of my head.

Comment: Barring any overrides of this theming function, this div will appear for any element that has a `#description` key.